# TFS SDK - Getting the network credential prompt

Tags: tfs, sdk, ms-word, tfs-sdk

I am trying to get the network prompt so that user can provide the credentials.
I saw [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130172%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and It does not help. Could somebody provide a more complete example?
The goal is is to get this from a Word Add-in so that I can create work items in TFS from the function points mentioned in the word document. So, somebody writes the function points in a document, closes it and It would ask for the network credentials so that It can create work items in the TFS.

Comment: What version of TFS are you targeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the UICredentialsProvider when connecting. Here's an example that shows how you would connect to a TFS 2010 Project Collection:

```
// Connect to a project collection by Uri
try
{
    var projectCollectionUri = new Uri("http://tfs2010:8080/tfs/MyCollection");
    var projectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(projectCollectionUri, new UICredentialsProvider())
    projectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();
}
catch (TeamFoundationServerUnauthorizedException ex)
{
    // handle access denied
}
catch (TeamFoundationServiceUnavailableException ex)
{
    // handle service unavailable
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    // handle other web exception
}
```

Comment: Gets to the WebException block with "The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden." It does not ask for the credentials.

Comment: Jim, my bad. The TFS uri was bad. Now It does not throw any exception. However, It does not ask me any credentials. I didn't get any prompt. Now when I connect to my team project through VS 2010, then also It does not ask me any credentials. Does It mean It is making used of the "saved" credentials? When It would give me the prompt for credentials?

Comment: Yes, it will use cached credentials when available. Otherwise, it should prompt.